# Html issue with span being fixed

Tags: html, css

In [my page](http://ripemovies.com/released/2013/best-action-movies) there is section where I am displaying stars like:

```
* * * * * * * *
```

And at the end I want to write rating like 7/10 in straight line.

I tried many things but not able to solve it. I tried `float:left` and `float:right`.

In link
http://ripemovies.com/released/2013/best-action-movies

code causing issue :

```
<span class="stars" style="margin-left:250px;margin-top:10px;">
   <span style="width: 128px;"></span>
</span>
```

Comment: Please bear in mind that it's really helpful to provide a full, small, working example of your problem, including the CSS as well as the HTML, so people can work on the details of your issue without digging through the whole code to your site. Reproducing your problem in a small test environment like jsfiddle.net can be extremely helpful.

Comment: will take care from next time

Answer (score 1):

You could just float the elements within it's own dedicated rating container

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/AZ9zt/

```
.rating img {
    width:50px;
    float: left;
}
.rating p { 
  line-height: 45px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't tag things onto the end of your stars at the moment because they're styled as `block`. Change the stars to `inline-block`, then just tag your rating onto the end as a span.

`inline-block` will still allow you to do the block stylings you need to make the stars work, while letting the next element, your textual rating, continue on the same line.

Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/XrCjq/2/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing element types. `span` is "inline" element like text, while `margin` used on "block" elements like `div`.

Is what you're trying to achieve something like this? You could put `<img style="display: block;">` with stars here instead of divs and set proper vertical aligns.

```
<div style="clear: both;">content</div>
<div style="background: black; height: 30px; width: 30px; display: block; float: left; margin: 1px;"></div>
<div style="background: black; height: 30px; width: 30px; display: block; float: left; margin: 1px;"></div>
<div style="background: black; height: 30px; width: 30px; display: block; float: left; margin: 1px;"></div>
<div style="background: black; height: 30px; width: 30px; display: block; float: left; margin: 1px;"></div>
<div style="background: black; height: 30px; width: 30px; display: block; float: left; margin: 1px;"></div>
<div style="display: block; float: left; margin: 1px; height: 30px;">5/10</div>
<div style="clear: both;">content</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zP49p/